# Reconfigure store conditionally and remove reconfiguration

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs5

To remove the reconfiguration store on a grid, i have to reconfigure store again with the original columns or is there a simpler way to do this?

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/231m

Comment: No, there isn't. "reconfigure" destroys the existing columns to save memory because it doesn't know that you want to alternate between two sets. If you want to switch between two column sets, especially if they are similar, you *could* be better off if you `hide()` and `show()` the columns.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.I'll follow your suggestion.